# SQL - Concatenation of expression error

Tags: sql

I am currently working through a book called 'SQL queries for Mere Mortals' and am having a major issue with 'Concatenation of Expressions'.

I am trying to run a very simple command as follows:

```
SELECT EmpFirstName || ' ' || EmpLastName,
       'Phone Number: ' || EmpPhoneNumber 
  FROM Employees
```

However, `SQL Server 2008R2` and `SQL Server 2005` are both giving me the same error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '|'.
```

I am bemused because I am following the text of the book and this should work, but it is not.

Comment: You get the error because SQL Server uses non-standard syntax for string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `+` instead of `||`

```
SELECT EmpFirstName + ' ' + EmpLastName, 'Phone Number: ' + EmpPhoneNumber 
FROM Employees
```

Correct concatenation symbol on sql server is `+`.

Comment: `||` is the symbol used by most databases and in the SQL standard, it's not specific to Oracle.